# LVM no more mounted at boot after upgrade to 20.04 "mpath* is duplicate for ..."

Tags: 20.04, lvm, multipath

I was using a setup using `FCP-disks` -> `Multipath` -> `LVM` not being mounted anymore after an upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04.

I was seeing these errors at boot - I thought that is ok to sort out duplicates:

```
May 28 09:00:43 s1lp05 lvm[746]:   WARNING: Not using device /dev/sdd1 for PV q1KTMM-fkpM-Ewvm-T4qd-WgO8-hV79-qXpUpb.
May 28 09:00:43 s1lp05 lvm[746]:   WARNING: Not using device /dev/sdi1 for PV q1KTMM-fkpM-Ewvm-T4qd-WgO8-hV79-qXpUpb.
May 28 09:00:43 s1lp05 lvm[746]:   WARNING: Not using device /dev/sdn1 for PV q1KTMM-fkpM-Ewvm-T4qd-WgO8-hV79-qXpUpb.
May 28 09:00:43 s1lp05 lvm[746]:   WARNING: PV q1KTMM-fkpM-Ewvm-T4qd-WgO8-hV79-qXpUpb prefers device /dev/sds1 because device was seen first.
May 28 09:00:43 s1lp05 lvm[746]:   WARNING: PV q1KTMM-fkpM-Ewvm-T4qd-WgO8-hV79-qXpUpb prefers device /dev/sds1 because device was seen first.
May 28 09:00:43 s1lp05 lvm[746]:   WARNING: PV q1KTMM-fkpM-Ewvm-T4qd-WgO8-hV79-qXpUpb prefers device /dev/sds1 because device was seen first.
```

But then later auto-activation fails on duplicates

```
May 28 09:00:56 s1lp05 systemd[1]: Starting LVM event activation on device 253:8...
May 28 09:00:56 s1lp05 lvm[1882]:   pvscan[1882] PV /dev/mapper/mpathd-part1 is duplicate for PVID q1KTMMfkpMEwvmT4qdWgO8hV79qXpUpb on 253:8 and 8:49.
May 28 09:00:57 s1lp05 systemd[1]: lvm2-pvscan@253:8.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=5/NOTINSTALLED
May 28 09:00:57 s1lp05 systemd[1]: lvm2-pvscan@253:8.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 28 09:00:57 s1lp05 systemd[1]: Failed to start LVM event activation on device 253:8.
```

And finally giving up:

```
May 28 09:02:12 s1lp05 systemd[1]: dev-vgdisks-lv_tmp.device: Job dev-vgdisks-lv_tmp.device/start timed out.
```

`lvdisplay` reported the devices then as `LV Status              NOT available`

It seems LVM now scans more (or the kernel presents more) devices. I didn't have these issues on 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution and want to document it here for everyone else that might face the same.

Realizing that the root cause was the duplicate device I thought I'd filter the others out.
So I added these to `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` (the second line since the bug triggered with pvscan/lvmmetad)

```
filter = [ "a|/dev/dasd*|", "a|/dev/mapper/mpath*|", "r|.*|"]
global_filter = [ "a|/dev/dasd*|", "a|/dev/mapper/mpath*|", "r|.*|"]
```

I knew this is needed at boot, so to get that config into boot time initrframfs I was running:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Yet while so far it seemed to be a normal "need to update config after upgrade case" (which still would be worth to know about) things didn't work out.

Interestingly I found a `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf.dpkg-dist` file from the upgrade and remembered that I wanted to keep my old one. But this was the problem.
After restoring the packages conffile and adding the two lines above again things started to work.

```
sudo cp /etc/lvm/lvm.conf.dpkg-dist /etc/lvm/lvm.conf
# same steps as above for filters and update-initramfs
```

I haven't kept my old `lvm.conf` to analyze the case in detail, but the Lessons-learned for me for lvm.conf is to save my old file and carry any custom config into the new default file (instead of keeping the old config).

I hope this helps someone else as well.